# SQL syntax does not give errors but displays wrong data

Tags: php, sql

I'm just new here.

I would like to ask if my following SQL is correct and where did I do wrong?

This is my SQL in my php file

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblAlumni WHERE  fname LIKE '%$search_file%' or mname LIKE '%$search_file%' or lname LIKE '%$search_file%' AND alum_status LIKE 2"`

It got no errors whatsoever but it doesn't display the correct data.

This is my table

[Click here](https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aj8SUzzqy6-BmAEWJIkGu_a6KDwT)

and the result if i've search it or query it is this

[Click here](https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aj8SUzzqy6-BmAJoWDuuBKrvK1qv)
Thank you for future answers.

Comment: What does it display? What should it display? If `$search_file` is not being handled before putting it in the you've opened yourself to SQL injections (depending on how you are handling it could still be open). You are best off to use parameterized queries.

Comment: it's in the link sir. sorry its on 1drv.

Comment: I clicked the link took a while to load, I'm on DSL so maybe it's just me..

Comment: i'm using mysqli, and it's just for education purposes. :)

Comment: `mysqli` does nothing to prevent SQL injections by default. Best to learn the right way first :),  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query will be executed like this

```
SELECT *
FROM   tblAlumni
WHERE  fname LIKE '%$search_file%'
        OR mname LIKE '%$search_file%'
        OR ( lname LIKE '%$search_file%'
             AND alum_status LIKE 2 )
```

because `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`. Parenthesis are very important for execution of `Where` clause

```
SELECT *
FROM   tblAlumni
WHERE  ( fname LIKE '%$search_file%'
          OR mname LIKE '%$search_file%'
          OR lname LIKE '%$search_file%' )
       AND alum_status = 2
```

Use `=` instead of `LIKE` when you are looking for exact match it makes more sense to me

**Update :**

```
SELECT *
FROM   tblAlumni
WHERE  ( fname LIKE '%$search_file%'
          OR mname LIKE '%$search_file%'
          OR lname LIKE '%$search_file%' )
       AND alum_status LIKE 2
       AND yeargrad LIKE '$year'
```

Comment: Thanks, that's was fast. You're a great help!

Comment: sir i've forgot to put one data from the database. `$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblAlumni WHERE  (fname LIKE '%$search_file%' or mname LIKE '%$search_file%' or lname LIKE '%$search_file%', yeargrad LIKE '2017') AND alum_status LIKE 2"`.. is this correct?

Comment: @IKenat - No wrong you cannot have comma like that. Do you mean `AND` instead of comma

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tblAlumni WHERE  (fname LIKE '%$search_file%' or mname LIKE '%$search_file%' or lname LIKE '%$search_file%' AND yeargrad LIKE '$year') AND alum_status LIKE 2 ` this is what I've come up to.

Comment: Thank you sir. This was it. :) I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @IKenat If you are doing a direct comparison I'd use the `=` instead of `like`.